# Android - GridView line border

Tags: android, gridview

I'm new to android. How can I set single border lines to gridview? (I want just horizontally not vertically). I tried the backgrounds color change and then the spacing, but it gives also vertical lines. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047369/how-to-set-border-of-gridview-on-android)  also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309422/how-to-give-single-line-border-to-gridview-android)

Comment: As you are new [follow this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaCW4uL4P6c) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NoHxfIu0MQ&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa) may help you.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18309422/1817673